# Как выделить элемент в listBox с точным значением?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как выделить только один элемент, который точно соответствует значению? Например, в списке есть такие значения:

```
1 - выделяется
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10 - выделяется
11 - выделяется
12 - выделяется
13 - выделяется
14 - выделяется
15 - выделяется
```

Если в поле `textBox1` указать значение `1` то выделяются все элементы содержащие это значение: `1` + `10` + `11` + `12` + `13` + `14` + `15`

```
listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();
for (int i = listBoxPatch.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
    {
        listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Equals(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))`?

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените сравнение на то, что одна строка содержится в другой ([`Contains`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2)) на сравнение равенства (`==`):

```
if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().ToLower()==textBox1.Text.ToLower())
```

Убедитесь также, точно ли Вам здесь нужен `ToLower`. Если нужно сравнивать без учета регистра, рассмотрите возможность использования [`Equals`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_StringComparison_) с аргументом `StringComparison`.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку о `ToLower` теперь выделяется по регистру.