# Как сравнить значение из textBox в listBox с учетом регистра?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как преобразовать найденное значение в `listBox` в читаемый вид? Когда значение в `texBox` одинаково, но отличается регистром, поиск значения не срабатывает.

```
if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(textBox1.Text))
```

Если первое значение равно `C:\Users\SERVER\AppData`, а второе абсолютно такое же но содержит заглавные символы `C:\Users\SERVER\AppDATA` поиск по списку не срабатывает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После добавления получается два одинаковых значения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам же в предыдущем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/953027/220553) ответ дали про `.ToLower()`...

Comment: Я бы не писал просто так, пробовал с `.ToLower()` сравнение вообще не срабатывает.

Comment: Напишите самодостаточный пример с `.ToLower()`, где явно видно что данный вариант не работает.
Если вы, конечно, делали что-то наподобие этого `if (foo.ToLower() == bar.ToLower())`

Comment: Кажется я понял в чём проблема, буквально через час буду дома, напишу ответ.

Comment: Я делал примерно так, и еще менял разными местами `if (!listBox1.Items.ToString().ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))`

Comment: `Items` - коллекция, а вы ее в String переводите... У вас должно быть что то по типу `...Items.Any(x=>x.ToLower() == textBox1.Text.ToLower())`.

Comment: Если используется привязка данных (data binding), то вместо `ListBox.Items` следует осуществлять поиск в привязанной коллекции и, соответственно, использовать перегрузку метода `Contains`, принимающую `StringComparer`.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрев на пример могу предположить что вот такой вариант вам подойдёт:

```
if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(textBox1.Text))
```

Такой код не будет работать, т.к. вы просто сравниваете две строки. И их регистр также.

Исходя из этого строка `APPdAtA != AppData`

Думаю код вида:

```
foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
{
    if (item.ToLower() == textBox1.Text.ToLower())
        break;
    else 
        DoSome();
}
```

Будет работать прекрасно.

**Удачи в изучении C#**

### Aqua_

Comment: К сожалению, этот код (`item.ToLower()`) не скомпилируется (. Так что до "работать" дело не дойдет, не говоря уже о "прекрасно".

Comment: @Igor вроде бы правил. Серьезная ошибка с моей стороны. Извините